# How to get adapter position in onCreate of RecyclerView.ViewHolder in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, oncreate

```java
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate
            (R.layout.tfl_conversation_item, parent, false);
    conversations.get(getBindingAdapterPosition(view));
    getAbsoluteAdapterPosition() ;
    getchildAdapterPosition(view);
    return new ConversationAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}
```

I used the above code, but didn't succeed. I want to get the adapter position in `onCreate` of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Viewholder creation is independent from position by design, if you want to use position there your item view type or viewholder binding logic is lacking. It would be useful if you explained why you "need" position there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `viewType`, if you want the value of `viewType` to be equal to your `position`, use the following code:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

This is the solution, but the work of `viewType` is something else, [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types).